# Throw an error whenever the user try to delete the contact which is not associated to account

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to throw an error from the trigger whenever the user tries to delete the contact which is not associated to account, but below code is not throwing error, even if there is no account associated to it.

```
trigger errorOnContact on Contact (before delete) {
  for(Contact c : Trigger.Old){
      if(Contact.AccountId == null){
          c.addError('you cannot delete record');
      }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the instance of the Contact record that you are iterating upon to check if the value of `AccountId` is `null` or not, instead of checking the [field token `Contact.AccountId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm).

The instance variable in this case happens to be the variable `c`. Your code to work should be modified as below:

```
if(c.AccountId == null) { // not Contact.AccountId
    c.addError('you cannot delete record');
}
```

Comment: +1 ... I'd probably add something like: `Contact.AccountId` is actually an SObjectField token. This value will never be null, as it represents a token for the Contact field AccountId.

Comment: @sfdcfox that's good point to add, will update my answer.